# Resourcebundle can't get Chinese resource

Tags: java

I have a resourcebundle MyBundle.properties in English and MyBundle_es.properties and MyBundle_zh.properties

I could use MyBundle.getString to get spanish but not Chinese, it always gets the english resources, what is wrong?

Is java not able to find it, I tried with no location, and with a location, it only displays it from the base. I put Unicode inside the bundle that it should use , would java display it in simplified Chinese?

```
ResourceBundle RBI = ResourceBundle.getBundle("MyBundle", new Locale("zh")); 
System.out.println(RBI.getString("Hello"));
```

The resource file MyBundle_zh.properties has only one line, why java couldn't find it?

Comment: Show your code how you are using `ResourceBundle`.

Comment: Have you tried using `native2ascii`?  http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-convert-chinese-character-to-unicode-with-native2ascii/

Comment: See the above code @PeterMmm

Comment: *The resource file MyBundle_zh.properties has only one key/value.*: so it shouldn't be too hard to post what it contains.

Comment: Also used -encoding UTF8 on cmd

Comment: Yes, it converted from Chinese to Unicode @PeterMmm